# ASP.NET Core Identity SignIn & Lockout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have seen two types of login with ASP.NET Core Identity in generally

One, on oficial github [repo sample](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.1/src/Security/samples/Cookies/Controllers/AccountController.cs)

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(...);
```

And another also in web [articles](https://code-maze.com/user-lockout-aspnet-core-identity/)

```
await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
```

In the end, both calls will sign a auth cookie for me, `SignInManager` also adds some sugar (lockout validation) etc.

So, is there any reason why I should not always use SignInManager?

I have custom implementation of ASP.NET Core Identity - without built-in EF, I have to override it with interfaces (IUserStore etc) because I am connecting to legacy PostgreSQL databaze with completely different schema.

I must implement lockout validation, however on legacy database tables. Is there any ASP.NET Identity interface which I have to implement or DYI?

Thanks